# Can't answer a question in arguments

Tags: verbs, adjectives

If two people are debating, and one of them asked the other person a question and he got confused and couldn't answer this question. But he is impressed with this question.

Is there any verb describes this situation??

Comment: I don't understand your question clearly.

Comment: A verb, do you need? Why? Verbs don't necessarily describe situations. Nouns or adjectives might.

Comment: You've received two good answers that are not verbs or adjectives.  I suggest you add "phrases" to your tags.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for "mind goes blank". if you are asked a question and your mind goes blank, you cannot think of anything to say.

Answer (score 1):

It's a one word statement:  [**Touché**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/touche) !

used to admit that someone has made a good point against you in an argument or discussion:
"You say we should support British industries, but you always drink French wines." "Touché."

Comment: Showing entire links on the answer is unappealing, so I've embedded the links.

Comment: @NVZ Thank you. I don't know how to do that, and I can't see the link now. Where did it go?

Comment: See the [edit history](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/325696/revisions) or you can use `[title for link](link here)` format

Comment: But  'touché' is an exclamation.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Certainly. Clarified in my answer, which describes what the OP is possibly looking for, and possibly added a constraint without realizing the expression to fit the situation would not be a verb.

Comment: Is the past participle of a verb not a verb anymore? One could argue it's a shortened form of "vous m'avez touché!" meaning "you scored a point!"

Comment: @oerkelens It's the past participle of a French verb, which is given in the 6 English dictionaries I checked in only as 'interjection' or 'imperative'. So, claiming it as a verb would be committing the etymological fallacy.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's not an order, so it's not an imperative. The past participle of a verb form is still a verb form.

Comment: The verb toucher has never been English. The loan-word was imported as an interjection. / Notice that I'm not saying that  'Touché' is not the ideal word to use in the situation OP describes. I'm saying that it doesn't directly answer the question (which close-voters agree would be better edited).

Answer (score 1):

[**Fair enough**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fair+enough)

> That's reasonable; I agree.

For example, *"I'll wait just one more day.-Fair enough, you've been very patient."*

Comment: Is there any **verb** [which] describes this situation?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Fair enough, let me edit my answer

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm not a native speaker. How does a **verb** describe a situation? Plus, it's unclear what OP is asking.

Comment: Your comments were/are fine; the question needs clarifying (before an answer is suggested). Certainly, the two answers given would be good were the constraint not present. But at present, 'stimie', 'floor' etc seem more felicitous.